# Getting data into a json skeleton through user inputs in python

Tags: python, json, user-input

Say I have an input skeleton like this

```
    "thing": {
        "name": "",
        "date": ""
    },
    "anotherThing": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "description": "",
            "expirationDate": ""
       
        }
    ],
```

How would I go about filling in the blanks through user inputs so it could look something like this?

```
    "thing": {
        "name": "Water",
        "date": "07/27/2022"
    },
    "anotherThing": [
        {
            "name": "Fire",
            "description": "is hot",
            "expirationDate": "05/22/2026"
       
        }
    ],
```

or something like that above depending on what the user inputs?

Comment: You would need to write some code. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

you would need to write the JSON as a file

```py
data = {
  'message': converted,

}
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```